# What does 'epic point' mean?

Tags: terminology, simcity-buildit

I have recently started to play *SimCity Buildit* and have struggled to understand the meaning of epic point.

For example, when I build a surfer beach, it says "epic point 2". What does that mean?

Can anybody please explain this to me?

Answer (score 3):

Epic points are earned by building epic buildings. An epic building takes 24 hours to complete, and during those 24 hours, you're set certain tasks that will earn you from 1-3 epic points. The number of epic points given by each specialization building is given in the building description. Generally, more expensive buildings yield more epic points.

The number of epic points that you earn while your building is being constructed determines whether your building will product bronze, silver, or gold tokens daily. The more of them you have, the faster your building will produce tokens. For example, if you earn ten epic points then your building will produce one quarter of a bronze token every day. 80 epic points yields a fraction of a silver token; 160 epic points yields a fraction of a gold token.

Answer (score 2):

Epic points are points that are earned by completing the epic tasks that pop up when you are completing an epic project. The more epic points it says, the better. When you reach 10 (within the time limit of 24 hours), you have reached the turtle tier which means when you've finished and upgraded the building, it will produce turtle speed token parts.

You can read more on EA’s Help Pages: [Simcity Buildit Epic Projects](https://help.ea.com/en-us/help/simcity/simcity-buildit/simcity-buildit-epic-projects)

Answer (score -2):

This is a good explanation but some information in it is now obsolete. The game has updated its epic buildings. Now you need 30 points to produce a third of a bronze token, 100 points to produce a sixth of a silver token and 200 points to produce a ninth of a golden token. At the same time you can now store 35 of each token instead of only 5.